# Spring: How can I test same class against multiple datasources?

Tags: java, spring, junit

Consider this example

```
@Test
public TestMyProjectIntegration {

  @Rule
  public JpaRule jpaRule = new JpaRule(H2);

  @Test
  ...
}
```

- I want to run my integration test against `H2` database in `localhost`,
- I want to run my integration test against `MySQL` database in `staging` // Jenkins

I initially thought of using [Spring Profiles](http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-31-environment-profiles) and using `spring.profiles.active=development` and `spring.profiles.active=staging` I can control, but

since I hardcode the `JpaRule` to be `H2`, I do not know how to change this property to `MySQL` when `spring.profiles.active` changes

**Question**
What is the spring recommended way to point to different databases during testing?

Answer (score 0):

You could invoke the test with a system property passing the database details like `-Dtest.database=H2` and change the value when invoking the test from jenkins

```
@Rule
public JpaRule jpaRule = new JpaRule(System.getProperty("test.database"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your half way there.... so in each profile you need the same bean id say `dataSource`

```
<beans profiles="dev">
    <bean id="dataSource" class="H2"/>
</beans>

<beans profiles="stage">
    <bean id="dataSource" class="MySQL"/>
</beans>
```

Then in your `JpaRule`

```
@Rule
public JpaRule jpaRule = new JpaRule(dataSource);
```

then make sure you just set the correct spring.active.profile in correct environment.